# do all NEAR blockchain transactions require a receiver account?

Tags: nearprotocol

reading through some [documentation here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1VRef627Y-Md1qAdRn0RFUojPxOs5nQmHyHBFYewwbZQ/edit#) and saw that part of the definition of a transaction is that all actions are performed "on top of the receiver's account" and also that the receiver account is "the account towards which the transaction will be routed."

also in the nearlib SDK, [the transactions interface](https://github.com/nearprotocol/nearlib/blob/master/src.ts/transaction.ts) includes a method called signTransaction that requires `receiverId` as a parameter

```js
async function signTransaction(receiverId: string, nonce: number, actions: Action[], blockHash: Uint8Array, signer: Signer, accountId?: string, networkId?: string): Promise<[Uint8Array, SignedTransaction]> {
```

but looking over the list of transactions supported by nearcore I wonder why do some of these transaction require a receiver.

> why would any transactions require a "receiver" except for maybe `Transfer`, `AddKey`, `DeleteKey`, and `DeleteAccount`?

amd I think of the idea of "receiver" too literally, as in "they receive the outcome or impact of the transaction"? and instead it's not the right way to think about it?

or is receiverId optional in some cases but the interface just requires a value to avoid validation cruft?

here's what I believe to be the [full list of supported transactions](https://github.com/nearprotocol/nearcore/blob/54b597cfc53de24aa7c9813eea87926ad9752aa1/core/primitives/src/transaction.rs#L37-L46)

```rust
pub enum Action {
    CreateAccount(CreateAccountAction),
    DeployContract(DeployContractAction),
    FunctionCall(FunctionCallAction),
    Transfer(TransferAction),
    Stake(StakeAction),
    AddKey(AddKeyAction),
    DeleteKey(DeleteKeyAction),
    DeleteAccount(DeleteAccountAction),
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, we don't have a good name to denote what we call "receiver". In some places in our code, we also call it "actor", because it actually refers to *an account on which the action is performed* opposed to *an account which issued the action to perform* (a.k.a "sender").

`DeployContract`, `Stake`, `AddKey`, `DeleteKey` require `receiver==sender`, in other words only an account itself can add/delete keys, stake and deploy a contract on itself, no other account can do it for it.

`DeleteAccount` is the same, it requires `receiver==sender` with one exception: If account is about to run out of balance due to storage rent and is below certain system-defined treshold any other account can delete it and claim the remaining balance.

`CreateAccount`, `FunctionCall`, and `Transfer` do not require `receiver==sender`. In case of the `CreateAccount` `receiver` should not exist at the moment of execution and will actually be created.

See the code that implements this logic: https://github.com/nearprotocol/nearcore/blob/ed43018851f8ec44f0a26b49fc9a863b71a1428f/runtime/runtime/src/actions.rs#L360

Comment: >> In case of the CreateAccount receiver should not exist at the moment of execution and will actually be created.


What happens when we do CreateAccount + AddKey? How we add initial AccessKey if we don't have a FullAccessKey for to be created account yet?

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually every transaction always has a sender and a receiver, even though sometimes they might be the same. Because we always convert a transaction to a receipt that is sent to the receiver, it doesn't matter conceptually whether they are the same, even though in implementation there might be a difference.